# Threadsafe logging not working with Task or Thread in debugger

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, invoke

I try to log text messages from a `Task` or `Thread` to a textbox on my form. For that i use `Invoke` and `InvokeRequired` methods to syncronize with the main thread, as i can be found in many examples on the internet. See `LogMessage_Delegate` and `LogMessage_Threadsafe` below. When i close the app, a boolean flag `finished` is set to true and the task/thread should stop the work.

This all works fine until i set a breakpoint on the first line of the `Form1_FormClosing` event handler (`finished = true;`). Then i see only the console message "LogMessage InvokeRequired", but no corresponding "LogMessage" and the app is hanging.

If i comment out the `LogMessage_Threadsafe` call in `Work` (only console messages), then it works again. The app is closing, as expected.

So, can anybody explain this behavior to me? I can find no reason for it.

Please note, i do the flagging in the `Form1_FormClosing` event handler, so the form is still alive and working.

```
namespace MultiThreadedTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //************************************************************
        // Fields

        Thread worker = null;
        Task task = null;
        bool finished = false;


        //************************************************************
        // Constructor

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            worker = new Thread(Work);
            worker.Start();

            //task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Work);
        }


        //************************************************************
        // Helper methods

        public void LogMessage(string sMessage)
        {
            LogTextBox.Text += sMessage + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Threadsafe wrapper for LogMessage
        /// </summary>
        delegate void LogMessage_Delegate(string sMessage);
        public void LogMessage_Threadsafe(string sMessage)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LogMessage InvokeRequired");

                LogMessage_Delegate callback = new LogMessage_Delegate(LogMessage_Threadsafe);
                this.Invoke(callback, new object[] { sMessage });
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LogMessage");

                LogMessage(sMessage);
            }
        }


        //************************************************************
        // Commands

        void Work()
        {
            while (!finished)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tread/Task Waiting...");
                LogMessage_Threadsafe("Tread/Task Waiting...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);  // Wait a little...
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Thread/Task Done");
        }


        //************************************************************
        // Events

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            finished = true;

            if (worker != null) worker.Join();

            if (task != null) Task.WaitAll(task);

            Console.WriteLine("App Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably found old articles. Neither `Invoke` nor `InvokeRequired` are used since .NET 4.5 and `async/await`. Raw threads aren't used in general. Reporting progress/Logging is done using .NET's IProgress<T> and Progress<T> classes, as explained in [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: What are you trying to do? You could simplify the code a lot by using a timer, `async/await` and `Progress<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use raw threads since .NET 4 with the introduction of Tasks. Invoke wasn't needed either but became obsolete since .NET 4.5 with the introduction of `async/await`. 4.5 also introduced thread-safe progress reporting and cancellation with the [IProgress< T> inteface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Progress< T> implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx), as explained in [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

`Progress<T>` calls its delegate on the thread it was created on, in this case the UI thread. You can pass the interface to any background method (task, thread method etc) and use it to report progress.

Given that the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2, you can assume these classes will always be available. BTW, TLS 1.2 support was added in 4.5.2 so any holdouts are forced to upgrade already, as they find they can't connect to GMail or other services that demand TLS 1.2.

Your code can be simplified a *lot* by using these classes. A quick&dirty form with a background timer and thread-safe reporting is the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    IProgress<string> _progress;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _progress = new Progress<string>(msg => textBox1.Text += msg + "\r\n");
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(theCallback);
    }

    private async void theCallback(object state)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            _progress.Report($"Boo {i}");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            _timer.Change(0, 10000);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        _timer = null;
        _progress = null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As for why the original code blocks, it's because `Thread.Join()` is called from the *UI* thread in Form.Closing. If the background thread tries to call `Invoke` to marshal a call to the UI thread, it will get blocked itself precisely because the UI thread is blocked.

This can be avoided by calling `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke()`. This was the typical way to handle callbacks into the UI thread before .NET 4.

The blocking behaviour can be seen in the `Parallel Stacks` debugger window (`Debug / Windows / Parallel Stacks`). When the form deadlocks, two stacks appear, one in the `Form.Closing` method and one in the `LogMessage_Threadsafe` method

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, but the code above is only for learning and understanding. So, i am only trying to understand why the corresponding message "LogMessage" does not appear. Do you know why?

Comment: @DieterMeemken then you should note that the code you posted is considered bad practice for .NET. If you have to write code like this, something is wrong. It contains many problems - the use of `Invoke`, using a boolean flag instead of eg a ManualResetEvent for coordination, creating a new delegate in each iteration leading to memory leaks.

Comment: Noted. I just came along this example and stumbled upon that problem. Even when considered bad practice, there must be a concrete reason why it is not working as expected. And that, for me, is the interesting part.

Comment: @DieterMeemken because you call  `Thread.Join()` and block in the UI thread in `Form.Closing()` while the background thread is trying to use `Invoke` to calll *into* the UI thread. Which is already blocked by `Join()`. This code is bad for technical reasons, not aesthetics. Tasks and async/await were added to avoid precisely these problems.

Comment: @DieterMeemken old examples used `BeginInvoke`, not `Invoke` to marshal calls to the UI thread. Where did you find this sample? You should probably ignore any other samples or tutorials from the same site

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) "Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping." Do i understand it wrong? I thought, the message pump is still working and can handle the Invoke by the other thread.

Comment: The message pump runs on the UI thread that got blocked by the call to `.Join()`. Besides, there are no messages here, it's one thread trying to call another. As I said, good samples used `BeginInvoke`, not `Invoke`

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks a lot. Can you post it as another answer so i will accept?

Answer (score 1):

If you're paused at a breakpoint in the UI thread, calls marshaled to the UI  thread via `Invoke` won't execute, because they run on the UI thread, which is paused.

But judging from your comment, that doesn't seem to be the issue.  So I would guess the problem is that, by pausing at that breakpoint, you've allowed the background thread to get into a state where it's blocking on `Invoke()`, and then you're trying to join that background thread, which will block until the `Invoke` completes, which will never happen.

As a separate issue, if you're accessing `finished` from multiple threads, you need to surround the reads and writes with `lock` blocks to ensure thread safety.

Comment: When the breakpoint is hit, i continue immediately. So everything should go normal, or? Can that have influence?

Comment: There's no reason to use raw threads or Invoke in .NET anymore. Thread safe progress reporting is already available through `Progress<T>`. The question's code could be simplified a lot if a timer and `async/await` were used

Comment: @adv12 That sound interresting. Can you explain how this blocking could be possibe. I think, it should not be.

Comment: @adv12 Since the flag is only a bool used for waiting, i think read and write can be considered as atomic, or?

Comment: @DieterMeemken That it's atomic doesn't mean it's safe or correct to avoid synchronization.  It is not.  It just means that any value that it has was some value that was set to it at some point.  It won't get spliced (which it couldn't anyway, as it's only one bit).